# jQuery options for method stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure if the question were asked already but I've live example so I hope my question may be useful. Here I've custom plugin for jQuery:

```
(function($){
    jQuery.alertSay = function(options){
        var options = $.extend({say:'open'}, options};
        alert('We are currently ' + say + '!');
    };
})(jQuery);
```

connected to the main index.html:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.alertSay({
        say: 'on vacations'
    });
});
```

And it doesn't work because of options, cause if I use simple method without any options, like this:

```
(function($){
    jQuery.alertSay = function(){
        alert('We are currently on vacations!');
    };
})(jQuery);
```

It works just fine with the link like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.alertSay();
});
```

Due to my poor knowledge in jQuery I'm unable to detect where my mistake is and it would be so nice from you to help me if possible. Thank you!

UPD:
Thank you for your replies but unfortunately replacing

```
alert('We are currently ' + say + '!');
```

with

```
alert('We are currently ' + options.say + '!');
```

change nothing, no alert at all. But I've some errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } hallo.js:3
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new p.fn.init(a,b,c)} has no method 'alertSay' (in the html on string $.alertSay({)
```

Comment: [Your code, with the suggested fix, works fine.](http://jsbin.com/oloruq/1)

Comment: See my updated answer, you also have a `}` where you want a `)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your 1st snippet code replace `say` with `options.say`

```
(function($){
    jQuery.alertSay = function(options){
        var options = $.extend({say:'open'}, options); // some error here
        alert('We are currently ' + options.say + '!');
    };
})(jQuery);
```

jsfiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/abforce/TuSwU/1/)

Comment: @Mike don't you think it would help people help you if you were more explicit about what "doesn't work" means?  Like, are there errors in the console? Does something happen, but the wrong thing?  People aren't psychic.

Comment: My bad I don't know how to check errors but I really appreciate that people try to help me and by my side I always try to provide as much info as I have...

Comment: @Mike well you should *at least* open up the browser developer console. Hit F12.

Comment: Thank you for an advice! Here is an erros:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } hallo.js:3
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new p.fn.init(a,b,c)} has no method 'alertSay'

Comment: @Mike ok, so that would be a significant problem. If the browser encounters syntax errors in your code, it won't run at all. Fix the syntax errors and try again.

Comment: @ABFORCE: *"`var options = $.extend( options , {say:'open'});`"* It's not a good idea to modify the object passed into the function, and doing this will overwrite any `say` option passed in. The way the OP is doing it (but without the syntax error) is better.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It's works brilliant. Next time I've to use console and pay more attention to the syntax!.. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
alert('We are currently ' + say + '!');
// -------------------------^
```

You want

```
alert('We are currently ' + options.say + '!');
```

The first one is looking for a *variable* called `say`. The second is looking for the property `say` on your `options` object.

---

You also have a `}` where you mean to have a `)`:

```
var options = $.extend({say:'open'}, options};
// -----------------------------------------^
```

should be

```
var options = $.extend({say:'open'}, options);
```

With those two fixes, [it runs fine](http://jsbin.com/adiyas/1) ([source](http://jsbin.com/adiyas/1/edit)).